# iOS custom idle timer

Tags: ios, timeout, python-idle

In an iOS enterprise app i need to implement an idle timeout. The application's idleTimerDisabled property is set to yes, that's not what I want.

It's a journal type of application for an exhibition, in which the app should jump back to the first page after a specific time. Is there some way that doesn't need me to adjust each touch/gesture callback with a function that resets the timer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override UIApplication::sendEvent to reset the timer, e.g. see the accepted answer here:

[iPhone: Detecting user inactivity/idle time since last screen touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch)

Comment: perfect thank you! didnt find that other answer!