# iOS: session + changing IP-addresses; how to handle it on the client?

Tags: ios, http, session, ip

in my iPhone/iPad-app I've got to deal with a server which determines sessions (not only, but also) according to the IP-address. The problem now is that with some providers, the phone's IP address changes after a few seconds and therefore the server can't recognize the session any more.

Is there any way to handle this on the client and "help" the server to stay unchanged without configuration changes? Or is it only possible serverside?

I'm not using a library (ASIHTTP-request, e.g.), but only NSURLConnection.

Comment: Follow below link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch

Regards,
Bhat

Answer (score 0):

Nope, nothing you can do client side. You will have to configure the server to accept session ID only.

Comment: thanks for your answer, baswell... are you sure about that? sometimes it it seems to me like it worked before but now it doesn't... I may be wrong, so: are you sure there's nothing I can do on client side?