# form's onsubmit with UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, onsubmit

I have this form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="window.open('http://www.google.com','Google','width=800,height=500,top=5000,left=6000,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="doSubmit();" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And the javascript that belongs to it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSubmit () {
        form1.submit();
    }
</script>
```

When I test it in the native safari app all goes well and the onsubmit action opens a new tab, but when I test it in a UIWebView, the onsubmit isn't fired.

The form is submitted and registered in

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

and all methods are set to intercept popups with

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function( inurl, blah, blah2 ) {  document.location = 'newTab:'+inurl; }"];
```

in the appropriate UIWebView delegate methods.

Any thoughts on why it isn't firing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that popup interception works? Are new tabs allowed in `UIWebView`s?

Comment: I wrote my own functions for it. New tabs are opened when testing with the window.open function alone.

Comment: Do me a favor and test whether DoSubmit() is not being called, or form1.submit() simply doesn't work, by putting a alert in there before form1.submit()...?

Comment: The form is submitted. Double checked it!