# Detecting inactivity of iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer, user-inactivity

I've taken reference from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch) about how to detect `inactivity` of App & code based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309535/1603234), this working fine in simulator but problem when I testing the same in device. If I've setting `NSTimer` `interval` to 60 seconds (1min) it works fine as my iPhone device `timeout` is 1min. If I set more then 1 min it lost (stop) detecting `inactivity` of App. So I set the 300 seconds (5mins) in simulator as its working fine. What I'm doing is when there's I find `inactivity` I'll pop to `firstView` of my App. Is there any ways that I need to configure so even my device locks it will still detecting `inactivity` in App.

You can see my code here, [InActivityDetectClass.h](http://pastie.org/private/3yknhwcnkbub6lnz7bhrug) and [InActivityDetectClass.m](http://pastie.org/private/1vrfboxmueyvy5u7q2n3dq). In each `UIViewcontroller` I've code like [this](http://pastie.org/private/i4gm6agvqi2bmytu8rtpaw) to detect `inactivity` of the App.

Don't find where I'm doing wrong. I think its all about, when device locks and app goes in background the `NSTimer` may stops working but it's not the case with `simulator` as there's no chance of `lock` or `offscreen`?

Comment: The simulator does have lock (Command-L) and home-screen (Shift-Command-H) buttons. When your app is inactive your runloop is not running so the timer does not fire, but the timer will fire immediately upon return to the app. I don't understand what part of this behavior is troubling you. From the user's perspective having the timer fire in the background vs having the timer fire just before the application enters the foreground again are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've found this `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled;`
 and set it to `YES` (default `NO`). That it makes my application always on & never locks. So the functionality that I wants I gets.