# Check the screen autolock time in ios

Tags: ios, settings

the option idleTimerDisabled disables auto locking. I dont want to do that but just want the screen timeout value.

Is it possible to check the value of the screen auto-lock time set by the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Detecting user inactivity/idle time since last screen touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently this is not possible .

Comment: hey thanks! I have another follow up question. Is it possible to check the setting for whether viewing on the lock screen is enabled?

Comment: BOOL Test = [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled;

Comment: But this would just give me the true/false value of whether the timer is enabled or not right? what i am looking for is the value of the auto-locking time.