# Calling method from principal class in objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm did functionality of timer out if User can't touch on screen for 10 minutes then my application directly goes on login screen.
For above problem i use sample code from here https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCUIApplication doing some changes in naming of class so my class is `PB_TIMER_UIApplication` instead of `ELCUIApplication`.
I calling `PB_TIMER_UIApplication` class in main.m class it implementation as following,

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([PB_TIMER_UIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I set principalClassName as a `PB_TIMER_UIApplication`

Now i create one property and instance method in `PB_TIMER_UIApplication` like following,

```
@interface PB_TIMER_UIApplication :  UIApplication{
    NSTimer *_idleTimer;
}
@property(nonatomic) int timerTimeOutIntervals;

- (void)resetIdleTimer;
```

Now i want my application show alert before going login screen/timeout session. If alert button press OK then my timer again start for 10 second. That why i create an property for `timerTimeOutIntervals` and that property and `resetIdleTimer`
 instance method i want to call in throughout application. So i trying to access property/method as like Appdelegate call, `[[PB_TIMER_UIApplication sharedApplication] setTimerTimeOutIntervals:10];` but it show me static error ,

[image]

My question where i'm wrong and what to do for calling property of instance method from principle class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i solve my problem. I changed my architecture of application firstly i create subclass of `UIApplication` and and set it as a principle class in main.m file. Due to this my `UIApplication` subclass run first then main `UIApplication` where `UIApplicationDelegate` are set. And that why i unable declare launching timeout intervals, my app goes in recursion.

After searching i got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch) link. I follow suggestion of @Brian King  in that link.
I create my own custom `UIWindow` class and put up all timeout code as his given Github link code.

Now my app architect is i put my rootviewcontroller on my custom UIWindow class, then show my custom alert view and write timeout/continue timer functionality on alert view buttons.
Note :- As per apple doc given UIResponder chain every touch calling it superview and finally call UIWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be inherited from UIREsponder.
For example:

```
 MyAppDelegate:UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

And you should use this way for get access for it:

```
 [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setTimerTimeOutIntervals:10];
```

If you want call your methods then try:

```
 [(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplciation sharedApplication] delegate] someMethod];
```

UPD: You can try use it:

```
 [(PB_TIMER_UIApplication*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] setTimerTimeOutIntervals:10];
```

Comment: Sorry friend it not working because my priciple class ran before so i can't able to declare or initialized idletimeinterval.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, i will suggest you to use sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event method in AppDelegate of application and in that reset timer if event touch phase type is UITouchPhaseBegan.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me.

```
#define gkSDUIApplication (SDUIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]

SDUIApplication *myUIApplication = gkSDUIApplication;
myUIApplication.myProperty;
```