# Getting all touch events of an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I've been looking for a way to intercept all touch events of an app.
I saw that I can add a gesture recognizer to the main window and get all the touches by using it's delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
NSLog(@"%@",touch);
return NO;
}
```

This way I don't harm all of the other touch events the app has.
The problem is that I cannot get swipe events and such this way. Moreover, I cannot override UIWindow sendEvents because my app is an outside framework.
I also do not want to add a transparent UIView on top.

Is there any other way to get swipes and other gesturs?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/309535/1176219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by using a custom gesture recognizer attached to the keyWindow and with using the method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Which also gives me all the touches and doesn't disturb any other recognizers.

If anyone know why I shouldn't be doing that, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

To intercept *all* touch events of an app, use a UIWindow subclass and override `sendEvent:...`. Every touch event passes through this bottleneck method. Be warned that you are now operating at a very low level and can easily break everything.

Comment: As I mentioned, I cannot do that as I'm working on a framework.