# Redirect to FirstViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm doing application with different Viewcontroller for different set of screens. I have button click, playing video and load html pages etc. If i open the app and my app in second view controller, then i haven't do anything within 1minutes for example any click event or any touch event in app, automatically Can i redirect to first view controller? Does it possible?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    video=[[VideoViewController alloc]init];

     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

    bgImg=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

    [bgImg setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];
    [bgImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_bg.png"]];
    [bgImg setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:bgImg];


    video_play=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    // [info_btn setFrame:CGRectMake(240,10 ,13, 24)];

    [video_play setFrame:CGRectMake(118,300,362,202)];
    [video_play setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [video_play addTarget:self action:@selector(watchvideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[rhymesbgImg addSubview:info_btn];
    [bgImg addSubview:video_play];


    watch_video=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    // [info_btn setFrame:CGRectMake(240,10 ,13, 24)];

    [watch_video setFrame:CGRectMake(180,600,232,60)];
    [watch_video setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"watch-video.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [watch_video addTarget:self action:@selector(watchvideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[rhymesbgImg addSubview:info_btn];
    [bgImg addSubview:watch_video];

[self performSelector:@selector(goToRootViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:20.0];


}
```

Click Event for Button:

```
-(void)watchvideo:(id)sender{


  //   [self performSelector:@selector(goToRootViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:20.0];

    [bgImg setHidden:YES];
    [watch_video setHidden:YES];
    [estimate_yoursaving setHidden:YES];
NSString *pathToBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToBundle];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(172, 210, 680, 380)];
    [web loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];


}

-(void)estimatesavings:(id)sender{

  //   [self performSelector:@selector(goToRootViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:20.0];

    [web loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];

    NSString *pathToBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToBundle];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    web_estimate=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    [web_estimate loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];

    web_estimate.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:web_estimate];


}
```

touch Event:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    isTouched = YES;

    NSLog(@"Touches happening");
}


- (void)goToRootViewController
{
    if (isTouched == NO)  {
      //  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


        NSLog(@"Touches Not Happening");

        [bgImg setHidden:NO];
        [watch_video setHidden:NO];
        [estimate_yoursaving setHidden:NO];



       [web setHidden:YES];

        [web_estimate setHidden:YES];


    }

}
```

Comment: how are you navigating the viewControllers?

Comment: [Detecting user inactivity/idle time since last screen touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah sure. you can pop to the root view controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**EDIT**

You can track the touch events by this delegate method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    isTouched = YES;
}
```

Add a method in your class

```
- (void)goToRootViewController
{
    if (isTouched == NO)  {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

}
```

Call this method from *viewDidLoad* as:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(goToRootViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:60.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

your view did load method add this code

```
[self performSelector:@selector(pushOrPOP) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

and

```
-(void)pushOrPOP
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[secViewController alloc]init] animated:YES];
     //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```