# Detecting iPhone's idle state programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a problem guys.I have requirement where my app should detect if the device is idle without any application running or without any user interaction from my application or at-least to know if the device is in home screen.What i am asking may be stupid but this is my requirement.Is there a way to achieve this. Help me

Comment: please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If this is a requirement then you can't ship your app. Why do you need it?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert My app is an enterprise app. I install my app over air on multiple devices.I have to make sure the device is idle,only then I can update it or install it.

Comment: @NitinGohel your reference link shows how to detect user interaction.this helps but what if an app is running without any user interaction then how to detect that.any suggestion ?

Comment: i dont think apple  provide any specific code. You can handle within your app as i given link.

Comment: @NitinGohel I know that.The link only allows you to handle user interactions,but that is only a part of my requirement

Answer (score 0):

OK, enterprise apps are different. I think this can be done.

Have your app record whenever it's launched by the user (the app delegate receives events when the app enters/exits the foreground).

Then setup a "local push notification" several times a day that launches your app in the background and checks the log to see if the last entry is a "did leave".

If it is, then load up the URL to your itms services URL to install the new version of the app.