# Auto lock in iOS application based on inactivity

Tags: ios

We have a order taking App with a pin pad and wondering how can we send user to lock screen after few minutes.

Do we need some kind of background process to check inactivity? Any direction please?

Comment: iOS Settings -> General -> Auto Lock... set the timer and wait inactively; the device will be locked in time.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch#answer-309535) is a good answer. In method `idleTimerExceeded` you can present lock controller to lock the app.