# Handle ideal time out in ios app

Tags: ios, swift, timeout

I need to handle the ideal timeout in the ios app using Swift. I have found some way through Objective-C but I would like to know how it can be done using Swift

Comment: Do you mean *idle* timeout? And I'd recommend posting the ways in which you've found to handle it in Objective-C.

Comment: I have just explored the following links [Icode blog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/09/19/timing-out-an-application-due-to-inactivity/) and [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch)

Answer (score 1):

By default Ideal Timer disable value is set to **NO**.

You can disable Ideal Timer like this in **Swift**:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true;
```

**Objective C**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: This settings is for ideal timeout for enter app. I just meant need to handle the inactivity of the users in iOS App. So that after particular timing I can logout the users