# Xamarin Forms Inactivity Logout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, iso

What is the best way to log a user out of my application after a certain period of inactivity has elapsed? I found a solution which seems might work for Android, but was wondering if there is a cleaner way to accomplish this for both platforms.

Comment: In mobile and web, this is usually handled by your server, through "token based security" where the token has an expiration set by the server. The server renew the token as the user accesses the application and returns an error when expired, so you can logout when you get that error. If you absolutely have to do the inactivity check on client side, you can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466761/xamarin-forms-check-if-user-inactive-after-some-time-log-out-app

Comment: I am not talking about the session between the client and the server. I am talking about the session between the user and application. I want the application kick them out due to inactivity, meaning no interaction with the application for x amount of time.

I'll check the link you provided. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a way to implement this ?
if yes, could you please share your solution here.