# Detect App inactivity/idle timeout in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I need to detect user's inactivity time in NativeScript app. 
I tried with few plugins (like ng-idle) but they are not compatible with NativeScript. 
I also tried to to emit application level event (in page router outlet) but it is not working either.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mobile context, you would like to track the inactivity in the native mobile application lifecycle. For Android, you can [extend the Application](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity) and implement some of the solutions shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android). Following this approach, you can do the same on iOS (overwrite the AppDelegate as shown [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/getting-started/HelloWorld) and implement [some of the native solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5269900/4936697))

Comment: Ok. But onUserInteraction() method is not returning anything? @nick

Comment: updated demo with `onUserInteraction` https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018/tree/master/NativeScript/issue_5423

Comment: Thanks for the demo. It worked for me as well. I was trying to implement it for IOS as well. I created a delegate and it is working but somehow I am not getting a callback for **sendEvents**. Do you by any chance have a demo for ios as well?

Comment: @NickIliev waiting for a answer if you have. Currently stuck here.

Comment: @Avijit Can you provide a link to a demo project