# Detect App idle timer/inactivity in nativescript?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I need to detect user's inactivity time in NativeScript app. Any help will be appreciated.

I already tried following link: [Detect App inactivity/idle timeout in NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788676/detect-app-inactivity-idle-timeout-in-nativescript) and was able to achieve success in android. But with the android implementation my oAuth2 callbacks Intent had stopped working.

Secondly I am completely stuck on iOS implementation with Native Script 7 as we cannot assign Custom window class when overriding AppDelegate. Please help if there is a way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my android oAuth2 callbacks issues by adding below code to extended android activity:

```
public onNewIntent(intent: android.content.Intent) {
this._callbacks.onNewIntent(
  this,
  intent,
  super.setIntent,
  super.onNewIntent
);
```

}

For iOS I went with adding a tap on page-router-outlet inside app.component.